# What is a Double Array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays

Conceptual question:

What is a 20x10x3 double array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply an 3 dimensional array with elements that are double precision floating point numbers. Visualize it as a book where all pages have the same number of lines and all lines have the same number of characters. Each `letter' is actually a double precision number in this case. You identify a particular 'character' (element in the array) from its page number, line number and column number. First index gives you the page number, second index the line number on that page and third the column of a particular character on that line.

Thus your example would be a book whose characters are of type double, with 20 pages, 10 lines to a page and 3 columns to a line. When you specify the 3 indices (that must of course be  within the limits as given by the array dimensions), you access a particular element.

Hope I have not oversimplified this answer...

Comment: Thanks for your description.  It was helpful.